# error bad execution (operating system course) need explain

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pid

I wrote in my noteBook the code below and I write it now in the xcode and this is the output by the teacher:

```
child reads : 0,1
parent write: 1,2
child reads : 1,2
parent write: 3,5
child reads : 3,5
parent write: 8,13
child reads : 8,13
```

I can't get the output because of this 2 errors:

1-Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. and mark the line `a[0]`

2-warning: passing argument 1 of 'wait' makes pointer from integer without a cast

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int shmid ,*a,*b,i;
    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 2*sizeof(int), 0777/IPC_CREAT);
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        b=(int *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        for(i = 0; i < 10;i++){

            sleep(1);
            printf("child reads: %d,%d\n",b[0],b[1]);
        }
    }

    else {
        a= (int *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        a[0] = 0; //after compile this line marked in red
        a[1] = 1;
        for(i = 0; i <10;i++){

            sleep(1);
            a[0] = a[0] + a[1];
            a[1] = a[0] + a[1];
            printf("Parent write:%d,%d\n",a[0],a[1]);
        }
        wait(pid);//warning message above
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You should always check return values. When using IPC, the `ipcs(1)` command is helpful (it should have shown no permissions on your shared memory segment).

Comment: hello where to put ipcs(1) in the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0777/IPC_CREAT`  should be `0777|IPC_CREAT`  (a logical OR, not a divide).

Comment: Nice catch! I've been looking at this for 5 minutes and didn't even think about it =)

Comment: ok thanks for the answer but the xcode output begin with Parent write:0,1 why not child the sleep(1); should got to the child and execute printf or...

Comment: Since they both sleep for 1 second, you can't be totally sure which will execute first, but the parent is a good bet.  Change the sleep times around if you want to experiment with getting the child to go first.  Also, you can fix the compile warning by changing that line to waitpid(pid, NULL, 0); but it shouldn't affect the output.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue with `wait`, see `man waitpid`.